# bash "read line" in while loop never ends

Tags: bash

I have the following code reading lines from a file and outputting a count:

```
while read -u 3 -r line; do
    echo $i
    i=$(( i + 1))
done 3<"$IN_FILE"
```

(I want to do more inside the loop, but this illustrates the issue).

This loop never ends for me. My `IN_FILE` contains 28.8M lines (as confirmed with `wc -l`), but it just keeps going and is outputting counts up to ~35M before I manually kill it. If I use head/tail to create a small sample of this file, it runs just fine and terminates as expected.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? Is there some special character that my file might contain that would cause the redirect to go into a loop?

If it's relevant, I'm running this bash script in Mac OS X terminal...

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `$line` after it reads the presumed last line from `$IN_FILE`? Also, what are the line endings used in the file? It's unlikely, but there may be a mismatch between what `wc` and `read` think constitutes a line.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check what the value of `$line` is at the last line because it doesn't stop there but just keeps going. Based on the output of od, there doesn't appear to be anything unusual about the line terminations (just a \n):     `tail -n 2 snap-twitter_cliques.txt | od -c`  `0000000    2   8   5   3   0   5   0   2   5  \t   4   6   2   1   6   4
0000020    7   1   4  \t   5   2   1   4   8   9   9   1   9  \n   4   8
0000040    5   3   1   8   4   8   1  \t   6   6   6   9   9   0   1   3
0000060   \t   3   7   8   4   9   4   3   4   3  \n                    
0000073`

Comment: I tried using `[[line == $'485318481\t66699013\t378494343' ]] && break` (where that's the contents of the last line) as you suggested (it seems like your comment suggesting that has been delelted tho?). It did not break at that line, so it seems like it's never getting to the last line even though I let it run until the counter got to ~43M. I'm going to try using split to break up the file per Ranjan's suggestion next...

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running, or did you take your failing loop and modify it to make it smaller without actually running it?

Comment: I ran that code exactly (it is modified from the original, but I also ran it after modifying to the above and got the same behavior)

Comment: `strace -p` the shell executing the script at some time when you think it should have passed the end of the file, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using `split -l 1000000 $IN_FILE` to break it up into 29 files and see if any of those has the weird behavior?

Comment: Interestingly, it works on each of the individual 29 files, but not on the joined file. That solves my problem for now, but it is curious that it doesn't work on the full file. I wonder if split could be stripping some bad characters out, or if there's some kind of overflow happening with the original file because it's too large? Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, it gets the job done for now...